# Haskell Error: parse error on input `='

Tags: syntax, haskell, indentation, ghc, ghci

**Specs**

GHC 6.12.1

Mac OS X 10.6.4 x64

MacBook Pro

**Problem**

I'm having trouble using `let` syntax. The following code refuses to compile:

```
module Main where

main = let x = 1
        y = 2
        z = 3
    in putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z
```

I tried tabbing in `y = 2` and `z = 3` even more. No dice.

**(Undesirable) Solutions**

The only way I've gotten the code to compile is either

1. Replacing hard tabs with spaces.
2. Replacing the `let` clause with a `where` clause.

Comment: never use tabs with haskell, always use spaces. Tabs in haskell are defined to be 8 spaces, which is a lot more than people often expect/set their editor to, so it is always advised that you use spaces. Any decent editor will allow you to make tabs produce spaces.

Comment: I found this an excellent visual aid, and an excellent guide on the subject overall: [http://echo.rsmw.net/n00bfaq.html#visualaid](http://echo.rsmw.net/n00bfaq.html#visualaid)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Saizan on #haskell explains that the **assignments** in a let expression have to align, not **let** itself. As long as the assignments line up, it's okay to use hard tabs or soft tabs.

Correct code:

```
module Main where

main = let
        x = 1
        y = 2
        z = 3
    in putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z
```

Comment: I found that the bindings (x,y,z) have to align vertically as opposed to assignment signs (=) of the 3 bindings which may be hard to see with this example.

Answer (score 11):

You simply can't control indentation correctly with tabs because the size of a tab is undefined.

Therefore, don't use tabs in Haskell. They're evil.

Comment: Or, for things that need to have a different level of indentation, use a new line. E.g., put `let` on one line and `x = 1` on the next. Then tabs are no problem.

Comment: Neil, I beg to differ (see my answer). A guy on #haskell was able to help me construct a compiling, hard-tabbed version. In fact, Justice's answer is correct.

Comment: I learned my lesson the hard way! I knew tabs were horrible but still used just because it never gave me an issue before. If you're like me save yourself a big future headache and take this advice, now!

Answer (score 3):

Indent each declaration in the let-block to the same degree. Also good form is to indent the 'in' and 'let' to the same level. Eg..

```
main = let x = 1
           y = 2
           z = 3
       in putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z
```

Comment: How do I do this with hard tabs?

Comment: Why do you want to use hard tabs?  They're mildly okay in languages that don't use indentation for meaning, but they are just going to make your life difficult in languages like Haskell or Python.  Like they are right now.

Comment: Python handles hard tabs excellently. One time, I had trouble coding Python through a web SSH client because the client couldn't insert tabs. I use hard tabs because I hate having to forcibly reindent other people's code to my preferred indentation width. Hard tabs don't have that problem, since text editors can view hard tabs at any width.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I put semicolon at the end of each line

```
module Main where

main = let x = 1 ;
           y = 2 ;
           z = 3 
in putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z
```

Comment: It will work with semicolon, but I won't use since the language works fine out it. Just for indentation, use spaces instead of tabs (or tabs correctly).

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on TAB characters in your source, the following compiles:

```
module Main where

main =
    let x = 1
        y = 2
        z = 3
    in putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z
```

where all leading whitespace is either one or two TABs, and the whitespace between `let` and `x = 1` is also a TAB. Viewed in vi's [list mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'list') to make TABs and line-ends explicit:

```
module Main where$
$
main =$
^Ilet^Ix = 1$
^I^Iy = 2$
^I^Iz = 3$
^Iin putStrLn $ "X = " ++ show x ++ "\nY = " ++ show y ++ "\nZ = " ++ show z$
```

Your life will be much simpler and your code prettier if you switch to spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I want to remember to tab between let and x every time. Also, any code I post will likely cause errors since readers will assume that there's an ordinary space there.