# Haskell example function error

Tags: haskell, whitespace, indentation

This function is defined in the book *Real World Haskell*.

```
--file ch03/Lending.hs
lend amount balance = let reserve = 100 
                      newBalance = balance - amount
                      in if balance < reserve
                         then Nothing
                         else Just newBalance
```

I try to run this in the interpreter, and end up with this error:

```
Lending.hs:3:54: parse error on input `='
```

Line 3 is "newBalance = balance - amount"
I don't think this is a white space issue so I am genuinely confused.

Edited to align the two local variable declarations:

```
--file ch03/Lending.hs
lend amount balance = let reserve = 100
                          newBalance = balance - amount
                      in if balance < reserve
                         then Nothing
                         else Just newBalance
```

The error persists:

> Lending.hs:3:68: parse error on input `='

Comment: It is a white space issue.

Comment: `newBalance` needs to be aligned with `reserve`

Comment: Are you using tabs or spaces for indentation?

Comment: Well line 3 is tabbed and then 3 spaces added to make the alignment.

Comment: @Caveman That's your problem. Change the `\t` (tabs) for spaces. In Haskell it's recommended to only ever use spaces, not tabs.

Comment: You are correct. Now it runs ok. Please add this observation to your answer so I can accept it! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell Error: parse error on input \`='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436758/haskell-error-parse-error-on-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Haskell has some funky rules for whitespace and alignment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation). In short, when using `let` you need to ensure your symbols line-up with the same level of indentation:

```
lend amount balance = let reserve = 100 
                          newBalance = balance - amount
                      in if balance < reserve
                         then Nothing
                         else Just newBalance
```

It looks like you're mixing tabs and spaces to do alignment in Haskell. It's important to remember that Haskell is nothing like "curly-brace" languages (C, Java, etc) where whitespace is insignificant, in Haskell it matters, and getting the col/char difference between tabs and spaces right is painful (and varies from editor-to-editor) so it's best to stick to using only spaces for indentation and alignment in Haskell.

When I paste this into CompileOnline ( http://www.compileonline.com/compile_haskell_online.php ) with the extra line `main = print (lend 5 500)` it compiles fine.